# Decrease the array value when another array is called

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Trying to make a HIT(x). when Hit called it decreases the elements( which are greater than x) of array by one and then print the array. and x is also an array which contains some element. For example. `AR[7 4 5 3]` and `x= [4 2 5]` then output is `[5 3 4 2]`. I am trying but not getting the relevant output. my code terminates only after taking the array element.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Kom1 {
    static int[] array;
    public void hit(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (array[i] > x) {
                array[i] --;
            }
        }
        printArray();
    }
    public void printArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxElements = scanner.nextInt();
        array = new int[maxElements];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxElements; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @ZouZou , hey m new here.. how i can indent?

Comment: If you are using an IDE, it can do it for you (`CTRL+I` in Eclipse)

Comment: just trying to understand your question better, can your output also be: [7 5 2 4]? How do you come up with this output?

Comment: Where do you call any of your methods? How can `x` be multiple values?

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast : See X= [4 2 5] and my array AR= [7 4 5 3] , So in AR 7 , 5 are the greater than 4 (element of x) so it decreases those two elements by one. so now AR=[6 4 4 3] , now for x=2 it becomes [5 3 3 2] and then for x=5 it becomes [5 3 3 2]
Hope now m clear.

Comment: could you replace your main method with a static (e.G. non-interactive) one that just shows your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm should be like this

```
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){

           if(array[j]>x[i]){
              array[j]--;
           }

        }    
    }
```

### Things you missed

- x is a array of elements. but you are using as single integer value
- you haven't define or get x
- your main method don't have a calling methods for processing

Comment: yeah.. So you mean , first i should take the array input and then X  and after that i can use this algo. right?

Comment: i think it should be array[j]>x[i] because it decreases only the elements which are greater than x. M i right?

Comment: yes. should call your processing method. in your main method you don't have calling method statement